# DVI-HDMI cables are two-way?

Tags: hdmi

I hope this is where I ask this type of question; if not, please direct me.
I just bought an HDTV (newbie) and it accepts HDMI.
My computer outputs video through DVI.
I thought I'd put the two together.
I went to NewEgg and found a bunch of HDMI/DVI converters.

Two questions:

1. Will hooking up DVI to HDMI make my video card recognize it as a display device and I would have a nice display?
2. If that is possible, which cable to get?  Any cable with HDMI and DVI on either end will work? Or specifically a "DVI to HDMI" one-way converter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Will hooking up DVI to HDMI make my video card recognize it as a display
>   device and I would have a nice
>   display?

Yes and no. Yes, if it works, No if it does not work. Depedns on the graphics card. I have some - even with HDMI - that are just unable to negotiate HDMI with my TV.

> 2.If that is possible, which cable to get? Any cable with HDMI and DVI on
>   either end will work? Or specifically
>   a "DVI to HDMI" one-way converter?

Any proper cable will work. Alternatively if you have a HDMI cable already, jsut get a DVI / HDMI converter. I would go this way, because sour next computer will most likely have a HDMI output anyway. SO, get a normal good qualtiy HDMI cable, then a converter.

Comment: I've not had any problems talking to HDMI devices from computers, but it can vary.  However I believe that if you want audio to go to the TV from the computer you are going to need to have HDMI on the computer end and you will see another audio card then.